# Code wont compile or throw an error when using scanf in C, gets stuck building forever

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, sublimetext3, mingw

I want to preface this with the information that I am pretty inexperience with coding.

Whenever I try to compile my code, it never finishes building and never throws an error. I then have to use Task Manager to stop stuck.exe (stuck is the name of the c file) so that I can try to compile again. I have narrowed down the issue to having something to do with the scanf function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number = 0;
    printf("this line shouldn't break anything. number = %d\n", number);
    printf("what should the new value of number be?: ");

    scanf("%d", &number);

    return 0;
}
```

When I remove the line that has the scanf function, the rest of the code compiles as it should.

I am doing all of this in SublimeText3 on Windows 10 and using GCC provided  by MinGW.

Any information you can give to help me would be appreciated, and If you would like any more information please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the program while an old copy of it is still running?

Comment: no, I make sure that the old copy is no longer running before I try to compile again. However If I do try to compile while it is running then I get an error related to that.

Comment: `scanf` gathers input from `stdin`; programs executing in Sublime's output panel have no `stdin` connected to them; thus they hang forever waiting for input that you cannot provide. You assume your code is broken and try to run it again, but the previous version is already running, which has the file locked, and the linker is unable to relink. Extremely common problem (but finding it on SO is very difficult). The answer to the question is to not run interactive programs directly within Sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a process `stuck.exe`, it means that the program finished compiling and was automatically started by the IDE/text editor.  `scanf` reads from standard input, but apparently the IDE does not execute it in an interactive fashion, so that you cannot enter the number via the IDE.

In your IDE, you need to use the *Compile* or *Build* command (and not *Run*), and invoke `stuck.exe` manually in a command shell window.

Answer (score 0):

Even my compiler is GCC-MinGW and i use Vscode, And your program works just fine even with online compilers.Maybe there is a problem with your C installation or check if your system memory near to full it might cause problems like these sometimes.